# Django: posting to foreign keys results in matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django, django-models

Models:

```
class CompanyList(models.Model):
    company_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)


class Reporting(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(CompanyList, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    year_end = models.DateField()


class CompanyAccountsExtracts(models.Model):
    reporting = models.ForeignKey(Reporting, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    data_type = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Now I have a pandas dataframe (company_accounts_extracts_upload) of data to write to CompanyAccountsExtracts. I am using the following code to do so:

```
for i, row in enumerate(company_accounts_extracts_upload.values):

    single_row = company_accounts_extracts_upload.iloc[i].to_dict()

    report = models.Reporting.objects.get(company=single_row['Company ID Number'], year_end=single_row['Year End'])

    DataExtract = models.CompanyAccountsExtracts(reporting=report,
                                             data_type=single_row['DataType'],
                                             source=single_row['Source'],
                                             value=single_row['Value'],
                                             )
DataExtract.save()
```

I am getting the following error on the "report = models.Reporting..." line:

```
DoesNotExist: Reporting matching query does not exist.
```

However, I'm 100% sure the company and year end does exist as I can see it in the admin view.

I think the error might be related to how I am posting to a foreign key as the Reporting foreign key which again is a foreign key from CompanyList?

Comment: Try updating your query param to `company__company_id=['Company ID Number']`

Comment: That worked - Thanks!

Comment: Cool, I will add as the answer. Please accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your `company query param` from:

`company=['Company ID Number']`

to:

`company__company_id=['Company ID Number']`

You are getting the error because the `company` param will need a `Company instance` and you are only using the `company_id` field.